# matlab: triangulate point set

Tags: matlab, triangulation

Given a point set (i.e a 3XN array of vertices), how can I triangulate it using matlab?
Assuming the point set does represent some surface of an object, and does not contain any noise.

---

EDIT:
The chosen answer gives a way to create the tetrahedrons of a mesh. I was looking for triangulation; for my specific case of a convex shape, the convex hull (using `convhulln` as suggested in the answer's comments) was enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting a surface from a set of interior 3D scatter points in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492806/plotting-a-surface-from-a-set-of-interior-3d-scatter-points-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Delaunay triangulation, you can use the class [DELAUNAYTRI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytriclass.html):

You create a triangulation object by calling

```
DT = DelaunayTri(coordinates);
```

where `coordinates` is a N-by-3 (or 2) array of vertex coordinates.

To access the triangulation, call

```
tri = DT.triangulation;
```

To plot, call e.g.

```
patch('Vertices',DT.X,'Faces',DT.triangulation)
```

Comment: `??? Undefined function or variable 'DelaunayTri'.` - I am guessing this works only for matlab versions > 2008 (which is mine) - I have voted this up, but is there an explicit piece of code that can achieve this that works on 2008?

Comment: @noam: At least your version should include `delanauy` (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay.html) which provides similar functionality. Thanks

Comment: @eat - delaunay triangulizes in 2D, i.e it gets [X Y] coordinates, not [X Y Z]. there's also delaunay3, but that produces a tetrahedral decomposition, rather than a triagngulation (it assumes the mesh has volume and not just a surface). Please correct me if you think I'm wrong

Comment: @noam: Yes, delunay3 creates thetrahedrons, not triangles. Would creating the convex hull (`convhulln`) work for your surface?

Answer (score 1):

use delaunay3 and convert the tetrahedral mesh into a triangular one

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5355-toolbox-graph/content/toolbox_graph/tet2tri.m