# How to plot this 3d figure(Horned cube). One equation

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

How to plot such figure in Matlab:
[image]

The problem is that i have only one equation and 3 variables.

Comment: Do you want it as a cloud of points, or as an opaque object?

Comment: Hm. The answers there are not really great. I guess I will add something there.

Comment: Actually I agree with @knedlsepp, I think this question should be open.

Comment: I will leave an answer: `fun=@(x,y,z)(1-x.^8-3.*y.^8-2.*z.^8+5.*x.^4.*z.^2.*y.^2+3.*y.^4.*x.^2.*z.^2) ;

[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2);

val=fun(X,Y,Z);

fv=isosurface(X,Y,Z,val,0);

p = patch(fv);
isonormals(X,Y,Z,val,p)
 set(p,'FaceColor' , 'red');
 set(p,'EdgeColor' , 'none');
%  p.EdgeColor = 'none';
daspect([1,1,1])
view(3); axis tight
camlight 
lighting gouraud
axis off`

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492806/plotting-a-surface-from-a-set-of-interior-3d-scatter-points-in-matlab

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I guess I'll write an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722500/plotting-implicit-algebraic-equations-in-matlab

Comment: @knedlsepp I will post mine there too.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Ok, If you are going to write an answer there on implicit surface plots in MATLAB, I don't see any need we both should do it.